# My use of float doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css

For some reason my float class dosen't work:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="BoxTitleSettings">
            <div class="left col-sm-6">
                Your Items
            </div>
            <div class="right col-sm-6">
                asuhido
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="BoxSettings">

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {float: left;} .right {float: right;}
```

Picture of code result:
[image]

Comment: Try `text-align` instead of `float`.

Comment: Looks exactly as I would expect it to. What are you expecting?

Comment: Michael, to make the asuhido float all the way to the right.

Comment: Benio, works, but still don't get why float dosent work

Comment: @JonesKing> It works perfectly. The block is floating on the right. Now the text within the block is left-aligned, but at no point you told it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text of the right DIV to be aligned right, you have to add `text-align: right` to the `.right` rule.

Comment: I see now! i'm trying to make the whole div float right, and not just the text. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

I can see you using bootstrap so use its builtin classes `pull-left` and `pull-right`.

```
 <div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="BoxTitleSettings">
        <div class="pull-left col-sm-6">
            Your Items
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right col-sm-6">
            asuhido
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="BoxSettings">

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to float just try this code:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <div class="row BoxTitleSettings">
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">Your Items</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">asuhido</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row BoxSettings"></div>
</div>
```